# Javascript To Add Up And Compare Two Table Column Totals

Tags: javascript, math, html-table, percentage

Im trying to achieve the following: Add the numbers from two table columns, perform the following operation on them ($price2 - $price1)/$price1 * 100 and then add the result to the top of the table in a special div.

```
<div id="mydiv">Percentage Gain/Loss</div>
<table id="mytable">
<tbody>
 <tr>
      <th>price1</th><th>price2</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>10</td><td>30</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5</td><td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>15</td><td>5</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So the desired operation would populate #mydiv with the results of ((30+10+5) - (10+5+15))/(10+5+15)*100    What would be the best way to achieve this? Also, if price2 should happen to be lower than price1 the output should be negative (I guess something like `-Math.abs` would work).

Comment: **1.** Find a way to get these values
**2.** Do the maths on them (look into `parseInt()`)
**3.** Put the value into the div.

Give it a try. If you get stuck, post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get the html elements that contain your prices and then do the computations.

```
var sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');  // restrict the search to one table
for (var i=0, length = rows.length; i<length; i++) {
  var tds = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (tds.length >= 1) {
    var val1 = +tds[0].innerHTML; // unary plus converts the value to Number
    var val2 = +tds[1].innerHTML;
    sum1 += val1;
    sum2 += val2;
  }
}

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = (sum2 - sum1) / sum1 * 100 + '';
```

Working JsFiddle: http://jsbin.com/IqARONE/1/edit

Comment: Thank you, this works great. Just one thing, I need it to output a max of 2 decimals, where should I add the .toFixed(2) method?

Comment: You should probably put it right before setting the value as innerHTML on the final line. I added '' to make it obvious the value will be a string, you can do .toFixed(2) there instead. Take care about precedence!

Answer (score 1):

I would just put classes to each `td`, something like:

```
  <tr>
      <th>price1</th><th>price2</th>
   </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="price1">10</td><td class="price2">30</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="price1">5</td><td class="price2">10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="price1">15</td><td class="price2">5</td>
   </tr>
```

Then, in your JavaScript, use the `getElementsByClassName` method to get an array of price1 tags and a second array of price2 tags, then use the `parseInt` method to get the actual value inside each tag and compute the wanted value. You then put this value using something like `$('#mydiv').html(total)`. Hope this helps.